# Spring Boot Directory-Based Database

Tags: java, jpa, derby, spring-boot

I would like to use spring-boot's repository feature to connect to a directory-based Derby database.  After much struggling, I realized that the derby DB that I keep connecting to is only an in-memory database.  Is there a way for me to specify that the database should be stored on the file system instead of memory?  I would like my database to be persisted (and able to be accessed) after my JVM is killed.

I have tried specifying the Derby connection URL to use a directory-based database using the following property in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:directory;create=true
```

My property did get read and used, but the database still didn't persist data between JVM starups and shutdowns.  It seems like a Derby DB directory structure gets created at the location specified by my "derby.system.home" system property, but when I restarted my JVM, it did not contain any of the data stored while in the old JVM.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using Hibernate. If so, the configuration of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is important. When you're using an embedded database, such as Derby, Boot defaults this to `create-drop`. The drop part of that will be causing Hibernate to drop all the database tables when you shut down your app.

You should change this configuration to better suit your needs. Using `none` and creating the schema using a `schema.sql` file, for example.

You can find more information about Boot's support for database initialisation [in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Comment: You are my hero!  That totally worked.  I was always using "create-drop."  I changed it to "update" and everything worked.  I guess I should have read the documentation on that field.  Thanks so much for the help.  P.S.  Sorry, I can't upvote you because I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

If the database directory is being created, but your data isn't persisting, there are a variety of things to check.

Firstly, did you COMMIT your transaction?

To examine, at a lower level, the actions that you are instructing Derby to do, modify your application to specify derby.language.logStatementText=true, as described here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper43517.html

Then examine your derby.log after running your application, to see what statements you are executing to Derby, and what Derby is doing with them.